# How to force elements to be on the same line?

Tags: latex, box, oval

I want to add skills to a sidebar of my CV created in LaTeX, I am using tcolorbox package to create an oval box around text, but each time I'm creating a new oval box the text (with box) goes to a new line. How can I force it to be added one after another in the same line?

Here is the code for the template (latex template twentysecondcv):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv} % a4paper for A4
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}

\usepackage{times,tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\ovalbox}{colback=gray!50!white,boxrule=0pt,arc=5pt,
  boxsep=0pt,left=4pt,right=4pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt}

\profilepic{alice.jpeg}
\cvname{Your Name}
\cvjobtitle{about me}

\begin{document}

\aboutme{}
\contact{contact}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\myskills{
\ovalbox{Skill 1} 
\ovalbox{Skill2} 
\ovalbox{Skill3}
\ovalbox{Skill4}

}

\references{references document 1}

\makeprofile % Print the sidebar

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    MAIN PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{About Me}

\hrulefill 

\section{Experience}

\hrulefill 

\section{Education}

\hrulefill 

\section{Courses}

\hrulefill 
\section{Other information}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Sure! I just updated the question adding minimal code in the tex file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit! Could you also link to the version of `twentysecondcv.cls` you are using? I tried with several ones floating around on the net, but they all were missing macros like `\contact`.

Comment: unfortunately searching for https://www.google.com/search?q=twentysecondcv+%22myskills%22 does not give any results which would allow compiling your code

Comment: I used this one: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-resume-slash-cv/mhyfwrmwjkbc

Comment: I think here you can also download the same template:
https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv

Comment: The class files you link to don't define `\myskills` etc. You document cannot be compiled.

Comment: Please make a MWE that is either compilable with the class files you link to or show the relevant changes necessary in the class file to compile your document

Comment: Ok, I'm uploading to Google Drive version that compiles for me:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zvg-Hw94oHUvdVFwOb4VH3778Y_NT_qx/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- to have all the `\tcbox`es in the same line, add the `nobeforeafter` option to the definition of `\ovalbox`
- if you modify the class file, it would be better to change the name as well (e.g. `twentysecondcvx.cls`) to avoid such confusion over different versions. [also change the first line in the `.cls` file accordingly]

---

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcvx} % a4paper for A4
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\ovalbox}{colback=gray!50!white,boxrule=0pt,arc=5pt,
  boxsep=0pt,left=4pt,right=4pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,nobeforeafter}

\profilepic{alice.jpeg}
\cvname{Your Name}
\cvjobtitle{about me}

\begin{document}

\aboutme{}
\contact{contact}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\myskills{
\ovalbox{Skill 1} 
\ovalbox{Skill2} 
\ovalbox{Skill3}
\ovalbox{Skill4}

}

\references{references document 1}

\makeprofile % Print the sidebar

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    MAIN PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{About Me}

\hrulefill 

\section{Experience}

\hrulefill 

\section{Education}

\hrulefill 

\section{Courses}

\hrulefill 
\section{Other information}
\end{document}
```

[image]